# undefined method `before_action' for Profile:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good afternoon, beautiful community, I have the following query: I have this error even though the method is well defined, if someone can give me a hand.
I want when a user registers to automatically create a profile for said user

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :patients, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  

  after_create :set_profile

  def set_profile
    self.profile = Profile.create()  
  end      

end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  before_action :set_profile

  belongs_to :user
  
  private

  def set_profile
    @profile = (current_user.profile ||= Profile.create)
  end

end

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  private

  def set_profile
    @profile = (current_user.profile ||= Profile.create)
  end

end
```

Comment: I'd be super happy if you could accept my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The error occurs because you're mixing up the model callbacks and the `before_action` that belongs in the controller in your Profile class. It should not be `before_action` but `before_save` or something like that.

See a list of available callbacks for the models here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

If you're goal is to just create a profile after creating a user the code in your `User` class is sufficient. No need to add another callback in the `Profile` class (but of course you can if you want to deal with other stuff there).